# Django __gt filter return the duplicate item

Tags: python, django

I want to fetch items from my model by using `time_created` as criteria.

If the latest item I fetched was posted at **12:45:44**, I store it in *request.session['time_at'] = 12:45:44* and use it to fetch item that are later than the last fetched.

`new_notice = Notify.objects.filter(time_created__gt = request.session['time_at'])`

This is supposed to return items with time from **12:45:45** but it still return the ones with **12:45:44** which is making me have duplicate of items I have already fetched.

How do I deal with this the right way?

Comment: are you sure that `request.session['time_at']` holds `12:45:44` as value ? print it before the query to check.

Comment: Yes. I displayed along the item to be sure.

Comment: You query is not supposed to return time from 12:45:45, it is supposed to return time greater than 12:45:44, which includes 12:45:44.001, 12:45:44.999 and all such values.

Comment: What is your `time_created` defined as in your model?

Answer (score 1):

Convert 12:45:45 (string) to datetime:

```
import datetime
time_at = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.session['time_at'], '%H:%i:%s')
new_notice = Notify.objects.filter(time_created__gt = time_at)
```

Comment: I believe Django would of thrown an error if it was trying to compare `datetime.datetime` to a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Django is storing time in database with more precision, than seconds. So if you `time_at` holds exact time of 12:45:44, query for database will retrieve fields that have time more than that just by miliseconds, so time of field retrieved from database can have 12:45:44.231 and it will be retrieved.